# How can I override commands with autohotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I want pressing the windows key and then the letter "l" to open a folder. I used autohotkeys to let me do it. When I do that command it locks my computer and then opens the folder. How can I use autohotkeys to override it from locking my computer. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, AutoHotkey simply isn't able to override the default locking function of `Win`+`L`. It might be something hard-wired into Windows (but I hope someone else comes along with a solution).

Comment: @echristopherson if it doesn't I will but a 50-rep bounty on this question.

Comment: You need to disable Win-L [in the registry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10987961/892420), with more info [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disableenable-lock-workstation-functionality-windows-l/).